# How to set entire column of numpy array 2D with 1D array efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array "A" of NxM dimensions and M arrays "B" of N dimension.
In a for (i:0,1,....M), I'm computing this B arrays, and I want to set the entire column "i" of A array. 
Im trying to access with A[:,i] but works too slow.

How to do this efficiently?

```
# Initialize array.
A = np.empty([N, M])

for i in range(M):
    # Compute of B (array N elements):
    B = ...An operation that results in a 1D array, different in each iteration
    A[:, i] = B
```

Edit: B values are different over "i" iterations.

Comment: Create `A` as shape `(M, N)`. Setting `A[i]=B` would be faster than `A[:, i]=B`. Because the memory is continuous in `A[i]` but not in `A[:, i]`.

Comment: Another choice is trying `numba.jit`. In some case it may speed up a lot!

Comment: So, `B` stays as constant across iterations?

Comment: No, B values are different over iterations. This is just an example.

Comment: Then, I think you already have the best version here, unless we could optimize on generating those B matrices efficiently somehow.

Comment: Are you sure the `A[:,i]=` step is slow, and not the `B=` line?  What's the relative size of N and M.  Iteration isn't costly if it's a few steps over complex calculations (N relatively small).